# Google Style Python Docstrings: Dictionary of Multiple Types

Tags: python, dictionary, documentation, pydoc

I'm working on creating a Google Style Python Docstring for a dictionary that is of multiple types.

Dictionaries of a single type are specified as the following:

```
"""Takes in a dictionary.

Args:
    input (dict of str: int): The input to this fake function.
"""
```

What if my dictionary is all string keys, but multiple type values. What is the appropriate docstring for a Dictionary of multiple values?

`i.e. observation_dictionary = {'velocity': 10.25, 'has_collided': False, 'weather_parameter': 'rain'}`

```
"""Takes in a dictionary
Args:
    input (dict of str: [float, bool, str]): Is this valid?
"""
```

**Bonus:** What is the appropriate docstring for a dictionary of multiple key and value types?

`i.e. observation_dictionary = {1: 'foo', 'bar': 2}`

```
"""Takes in a dictionary
Args:
    input (dict of [str, int]: [str, int]): How about this?
"""
```

Thanks!

Comment: I didnt get what the question or ask is here?

Comment: 1- What is the appropriate docstring format for a dictionary of multiple values?